# Excel grouping and summation

Tags: excel, grouping

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to add the number of "`Person`" for the `Date=28/02/2011`, `time=3`, `gender=1` and `young/old=1`. I want to take all the combinations for example: `Date=28/02/2011`, `time=3`, `gender=0` and `young/old=0` and so on.

How can I make it please with excel?

Comment: please add additional table with expected result for better understanding of your needs...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Excel 2007 or more recent, there's are functions `COUNTIFS(...)` and `SUMIFS(...)` that let you impose conditions for the count or the sum.  Sounds like `SUMIFS(...)` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You want a pivot table. Set the Value to Count of Day (it doesn't matter what you count but day will do), set Row to time and column to gender. You can set old/young to either row or column, whichever you prefer. Then look at the intersections for the values you want.